# Python detecting different extensions on files

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do i make python listen for changes to a folder on my desktop, and every time a file was added, the program would read the file name and categorize it it based on the extension?

This is a part of a more detailed program but I don't know how to get started on this part. This part of the program detects when the user drags a file into a folder on his/her desktop and then moves that file to a different location based on the file extension.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate based on the referenced existing answer. It doesn't address the core of OP's question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Periodically read the files in the folder and compare to a set of files remaining after the last execution of your script. Use `os.listdir()` and `isfile()`.

Read the extension of new files and copy them to a directory based on internal rules. This is a simple string slice, e.g., `filename[-3:]` for 3-character extensions.

Remove moved files from your set of last results. Use `os.rename()` or `shutil.move()`.
Sleep until next execution is scheduled.

Comment: An alternative to the string slice is to split on '.' and retain the last element. That would capture any length extension.